# Strange C# syntax

Tags: c#, syntax

I keep seeing the following type of syntax:`(string[])myList.ToArray(typeof(string));`
What does it mean when the object type is declared at the front of the object in brackets, before calling a method on it?
I am struggling to locate explanations becuase I don't know what this setup would be called.
Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: It's called a [**cast**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx).

Comment: That looks like a cast (an unnecessary one, I might add).

Comment: [`string[]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx) refers to an "array of strings" type.. the parenthesis make it [a cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) in the given context.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Not for `ArrayList` :)

Comment: @Leppie: `ToArray(typeof(string))` doesn't produce an... erm, `string[]` array already?

Comment: @RobertHarvey [ArrayList.ToArray(T) -> Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcyyh2hb(v=vs.110).aspx) (but who uses ArrayList?!?)

Comment: @user2864740  That was my other thought. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's Called a Casting, Casting is usually a matter of telling the compiler that although it only knows that a value is of some general type, you know it's actually of a more specific type. For example:

```
object x="any string";
string s=(string)x;
```

if we are using the upper one then it may possible that it will through the exception at runtime like if you are using

```
object x="string";

int s=(int)x;
```

it will through the Exception at runtime `unable to cast`

but if you use `as` oprator then it will return a null rather then throwing an exception.

```
object x = new object();
string y = x as string; // Now y is null because x isn't a string
```

Comment: Thankyou for this. Apologies for the offense caused by ArrayList. This is an example I kept seeing in a tutorial - so not production code.